# In XSD do you have to import the standard schema in order to use it?

Tags: soap, xsd

I am trying to consume a SOAP API and I tackled [this schema](https://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/ws-addr.xsd)

While this schema doesn't explicitly imports any schema it uses
the standard schema. i.e here

```xml
<xs:complexType name="AttributedQNameType" mixed="false">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:QName">
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```